# Symfony 2 error_bubbling doesn't work

Tags: php, symfony

For some reason error_bubbling set to false doesn't affect the form behaviour, and all errors are moved to top form. I'm using symfony 2.4.4. My code:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->setErrorBubbling(false);

    $builder->add('wrapper', 'thatformbelow', [
            'data_class' => get_class(new SomethingElse()),
            'property_path' => 'something',
            'error_bubbling' => false,
        ]);

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => get_class(new Something()),
        'error_bubbling' => false,
    ));
}
```

Subform

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->setErrorBubbling(false);
    $builder
        ->add('name', 'text', array(
            'label' => 'Arr',
            'error_bubbling' => false,
        ));
}

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'whatever',
        'error_bubbling' => false,
    ));
}
```

Validator:

```
Somethingwrapper:
    properties:
        wrapper:
            - Valid: ~

Myentitysomething:
    properties:
        name:
            - NotBlank:
                groups: ['flow_mail_base_create_step1']
            - Length:
                min: 4
                groups: ['flow_mail_base_create_step1']
```

As you can see, I've tried a lot of methods, but none work. Template is standard form() (via MopaBootstrap), but the problem lies in mapping, not displaying.

What might be the reason?

Comment: Messages are attached to a field only when validator is attached to corresponding property. Your validator could be attached to a method of the class so error is indeed global, what kind of errors you have?.

Comment: Yup, I'm aware of that. Added validation config in my post

Answer (score 1):

Later better than never, I had the same problem and the reason was that 
camel case of field name.

for example

WRONG

```
$builder->add('given_name')
```

CORRECT

```
$builder->add('givenName')   //should match your entity property NOT column
```